# Find invalid multibyte character in large python script

Tags: python

Our company is upgrading from SLES11 to SLES12 for our linux machines, and I'm having a problem with my legacy python script. It executes perfectly on the SLES11 machines, but crashes on the SLES12 machines. I get the following error message:

`Debug: ./src/common/unichar.cpp(52): assert "assert failure" failed in FromHi8bit(): invalid multibyte character
./[executablename] line 3: 70332 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)`

Could there just be a u'xxxxx' somewhere in my source code where xxxxx contains an invalid unicode character? How would I find that (Without manually checking every single unicode variable manually...)

Is there something else that could be causing this?
We use Numpy and WX in this script.
This code is running on Python 2.7.16 (I can't use python3, the libraries we need have not been added to our machines yet)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this is caused by Python? The CPython code base is written purely in C (no `.cpp` files) and would typically raise exceptions if it tried to load source files with an invalid encoding, not dump core. If it's dying in a `.cpp` file, that probably implicates one of your extensions.

Comment: Is there a way to identify which extension is causing the issue? Would that issue be caused at the import statement? (i.e., could I just write some dummy py files which have the import statements for various modules)